# WinForms-Preventing form conflicts

Tags: c#, winforms, git, dvcs

Our application has a central main form. Since we are at the start of the project a lot of buttons and controls are being added to this form. This, as expected, creates conflicts when merging our code together using VCS. It is also almost impossible to solve the conflicts since the designer part of a form is generated automatically.

I was wondering if there is a practice or workflow strategy to minimize conflicts in a form where several people work on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove as much logic as you can so your form becomes simply a view. This minimizes the conflicts - but it doesn't resolve them entirely.

Your best strategy is to make sure people pull from and push to your master/trunk/branch as often as possible so the conflicts are minimal.

If your team mainly works on feature branches, then have someone dedicated (or a couple of developers working closely together) do the feature merges back to your master/trunk. The conflicts will be many, but this alleviates the need for individual developers to track merge conflicts and attempt to fix them in isolation. The developer(s) responsible for the merging back to master/trunk will know what needs to come in/be left out and can manage it as part of their process.

Again though - your best bet is to make your form literally be a dumb view that does nothing but render controls. Everything else should be handled elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

The only techniques I've seen are:

- Refactor to controls so that impact is minimal
- Limit your UI changes to be just the designer or developer with best ux intuition
- Use the "lock" feature of the VCS system if your VCS system supports it.  That will prevent others from checking it out if you're working on it.

Answer (score 1):

.NET has a tool for that, it is called a `UserControl` :

- Separate your form in multiple custom UserControls, each of which can be developped independently. Eventually your MainForm would be the assembly of a few high level UserControls, each being itself an assembly of `UserControl` etc...
- Creating UserControl will also allow you to reuse them in other parts of your appliction, making it much more fleible and easier to maintain

You can follow [MSDN tutorial about creating a UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx).
Do not work with a single Form.

Comment: Doesn't really solve the problem, since the UserControl has the same issues: the designer code will be in conflict any time two developers are working on the same UC, and attempt to commit their changes.